# I'm getting multiple instances of render when forcing a margin shift on canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image: Image of bug result]

This only occurs after I do a margin shift. It is also a css transition effect. It does the same across FF, Chrome on both desktop and android so I don't believe it is a browser specific issue.

Is the renderer doing something weird? - or maybe a WebGl bug? - or is it something embeded in my code?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this bug is evident when I rotate the camera view using OrbitControls. All instances then snap into position once the control has stopped.

```
function render() {
    camera.lookAt( target );
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    renderer.render( scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    controls.update();

    sceneUpdates();

    render();
}
```

**sceneUpdates()** is object related transformations such as morph and rotations.

Comment: it looks like you're not clearing either your canvas (if you're directly rendering to the canvas) or a framebuffer/rendertarget if you're rendering to a render target

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer.autoClear